# Kernel32.dll missing in QT

Tags: qt

First of all thanks to those who will guide or give me a hint on my submitted issue. I am using QT4.7.4 (32bit). The problem is my QT creator can build some example project on QT but some aren't. If it can't build the project than it shows kernel32.dll missing. Can anybody tell me what might be the reason?

Comment: Could you detail a bit more on the error message

Comment: Are you running Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Next time, if you have applications and want to know what DLL's they need, I suggest to use a little tool called [Depends.exe](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).

After dragging the exe (or DLL) on top of it, it gives the full list of DLL's and the ones it's missing.

[image]

Since I build a lot of different types of applications, this has been a lifesaver. Simply find and copy the DLL's that are listed next to the application and it will run, regardless of Visual Studio version, SDK version or Windows version.